Why does Alien B, who can't see Alien A (and vice versa), crash their ship specifically into Alien A?
First, some exposition:
Alien A (from now on, Starfish) are a group of seven biologically immortal aquatic creatures. Their ship was built out of necessity to escape their home system (long story) and uses huge solar sails to propel a central ship, which supports an artificial ecosystem in zero-g. Most of their technology is based on extreme bioengineering and simple, industrial era tools. The Starfish have been traveling from star to star in a line for thousands of years (This may be an unrealistic timescale for our universe, but I'm willing to handwave it. Their world is smaller than ours), trying to find a habitable planet.
Alien B (from now on, Centaurs) are an organized team of intelligent creatures on a scientific/colonial journey. Their civilization is younger than that of the Starfish, but spent longer developing their technology on the planet, and only recently left. They discovered a way to produce and use antimatter efficiently along with a device that can move matter along extra-dimensional axes. They have constructed several dozen antimatter-powered ships with large crews, and used their Dimension Gadgets to shift the ships into a plane where activating these rockets won't damage their home planet, nor will the ships crash into any rogue/dark bodies. (Note: Shifting dimensions using my patented Whimsical Dimension Gadget removes the entire ship from the plane it was on, but attachments like sensors (if the Centaurs even have any? maybe the ship is automated) are still connected and will not be cut off - when the ship, which is in the Extra Direction, activates its engines, anything connected to it in the "zero" world appears to accelerate for no reason.
So the question - Why, when both the Starfish ship and the Centaur ship arrive in the same system (a pulsar, if that's important), do they crash into each other, killing all crewmembers of both ships?
Specifically, the Starfish ship gets there first and the Centaur ship returns to zero on the Extra Direction while inside the Starfish ship, tearing a hole through it and permanently locking the ships together, even if the Centaur ship moves in the Extra Direction. What could motivate the Centaurs (or an automated/AI system) to move their ship right there before returning to zero? If they are detecting signals from the Starfish, wouldn't they park next to them, not on them?
Anything from Starfish tech ideas to "the pulsar did it" is helpful - I just really need some ideas to jump off from!

"If they are detecting signals from the Starfish" - there's your loophole.

@Escapeddentalpatient. How so? Like I said, it would make no sense for them to return to zero exactly at the source of the signal - more likely, if they were able to detect signals (intentional communication or otherwise) from the Starfish ship, they'd assume it was coming from a body they wouldn't want to crash into, and park a few hundred km away, not right inside it, right? Or maybe you're seeing something I'm not - please clarify!

How do they even know the other ship's there? Sure, a scan of the system may have been performed for navigation, but if the target space hadn't been occupied by the ship at that time (and they had no reason to suppose it would be there), then - well, I'm not seeing the issue - if they simply don't see the ship.

@Escapeddentalpatient. The Centaurs don't necessarily know there's anything there - I am not asking why they wouldn't know, but why they would return to zero specifically at the same spot that the Starfish ship is.

They are sheep aliens and crashing into each other is how one greets a stranger in their culture. Sheep alien academics have been decrying this tradition for centuries, but sheep alien conservative politicians ridicule them as insufficiently patriotic.

@JohnO This doesn't seem very relevant, as I'm not asking to establish intra-cultural greetings. - and I did call them Centaurs for a reason: they're horse (shaped) aliens

@tenmillioncrabs Well, why are the Starfish at that particular point in space?  Is there something special about it — a Lagrange point, or the "minimal distance" from multiple planets, to scan them all at once?

Why are a small group of immortals, looking for a new home, hanging around in a pulsar system? They won't find a new home there, but there are many excellent ways to get killed, even without another species being involved. Slowing down into the system is difficult with a solar sail, and leaving will be equally hard.

Sensors not being cut off is surprising. Why not explain that "shifted" ships can only see large gravity wells (enough to not emerge in the middle of planets) and rely on special devices (or really good traffic control) near their own world to not "come out" on top of something important? Then they literally won't see the starfish, and it's a freak coincidence.

L2 point.  (The pulsar did it)
No matter how good your genetic engineering is, pulsars are nasty. Best observed from the far side of a planet.  Hence the L2 Lagrange point; in this case it's a pulsar planet (perhaps Draugr, the first time exoplanets of were discovered).
It's considered gauche to park a spacecraft smack dead center in the middle of L2, and besides, other planets' gravitational influences will throw it out of position.  Also, it's dark, and while that's great for scoping out the other planet, it is a bad ambience for solar sailors.  Their path was just barely in the dark, requiring little thrust to get back out, and giving them as much visibility as possible to the corona or other features near the pulsar.  So L2 spacecraft tend to do "station keeping", moving in some circular path that is most definitely not an orbit surrounding L2, with periodic accelerations to not fall out of the area.  Right now Earth has Gaia, JWST, and Euclid all circling around L2 in different paths.
So your solar sailors were camping out in the shadow of a tiny dead pulsar planet, keeping an eye on everything in the area, when they discovered, very near them, a little sensor array moving around with a reactionless drive.  (That being the other ship, also station keeping around L2)  Cool!  Let's bring it on board and study it!  Unfortunately, their initial electromagnetic scanning did something to break the extradimensional wiring array, so the other ship, losing sensors, decided to pop back into normal space to do repairs.
What I said above left a nagging question in my mind: how does a gentle electromagnetic probe interfere with something that can do scans on a pulsar?  For that, we first have to examine how the sensor array links extradimensionally.  From our perspective, the array is moved around by, essentially, an Emdrive - a microwave cavity with one frequency of radio waves bouncing around inside.  Allegedly (not IRL, it would seem) this can generate a reactionless thrust; here, we'll postulate this happens, and works by interacting with some additional electromagnetic dimension along the line of Kaluza-Klein theory or one of its modern descendants.  Only a small amount of the microwave radiation leaks out of the resonator, and the sensor part of the probe uses this to detect the strength of the rebounding signal.  The signal has to be arranged so that it remains locked in place to where the ship is in the other dimension.  When the Starfish detects that frequency, they send it back at the newcomer to see how it responds.  But this trips a safety on the sensor which detects leakage, causing the sensor to jettison itself so that it doesn't come out in a random place inside the ship.  This isn't unheard of, and the routine procedure is for the ship to come back into ordinary space to deploy a fresh sensor and recover the old one for analysis.

While I do intend to wait for more answers, this is wonderful! Thank you so much!

Also, the Starfish, while ancient and probably of superior intelligence, don’t have much meaningful electronic/mechanical expertise (their spacesuits are basically a bunch of purposed organisms in rubber casings, and they happened upon combustion rockets through desperate trial and error). They probably decided that immersing the sensor array in water or biosubstance was a good idea

I really love the "uhh what is that shiny thing, lets study it" aspect. and with the sensor array on board the starfish ship the centaurs probably don't even have any other choice than to phase back into zero space. Maybe the sensors can't even be jettisoned/removed from the ship while the ship is phased. How do you break the interdimensional link after all?

@datacube Technically, if they knew the array was in a hostile area, the Centaurs could disconnect the part of it that is in the dimension shifting bubble, letting their ship move away. I don't think they would have planned for this, though, so they'd be left pretty crippled afterwards

A question, before I mark this as Answered - if the Centaurs' sensor array stops returning data, won't they assume it collided with something and try to move the ship away first? On the other hand, perhaps the Starfishes' meddling caused some emergency breaker to flip, returning the Centaurs to zero automatically.

The sensor array was not destroyed.  It detected a leak in a sealed chamber for resonating microwaves (which was actually just the Starfish signal), so it shut itself down in an orderly fashion, including a final report, and jettisoned away.  The usual cause of such a leak is micrometeorite puncture.  The sensor shot away rapidly from its mothership, but the Starfish didn't see or couldn't follow that.  Instead, it continued approaching the site of the extradimensional connection which might still have been emitting microwaves.

I think this is a great reason, but keep in mind, something like the Sun/Earth L2 region is much bigger than one might expect - it's as large as the entire volume enclosed by the Moon's orbit, ~1M km across. And it is poorly defined, as it's shape is affected by variations in the Earth's orbit, other planets etc. The odds of 2x km-scale ships colliding on a single pass through such a region are ~1bn:1 against. However, one key thing is that they're in L2, sheltering in the shadow of the planet. If the planet is small, then that's a very constrained region.

@SusanW - Draugr is just 1/3 the radius of Earth and 2% of its mass, so it casts a narrow shadow.  I'm not actually sure how to define the size of the L2 region apart from that, since it's not a stable orbit to begin with.

@MikeSerfas Reasonable, and Draugr is close in too, which I think tightens it down even further. And you're right, it seems like "L2 region" is poorly defined, outside of "where L2-like effects predominate". I'm just keen that the OP avoids writing "the warp field is unstable because we're near the L2 point, it'll restabilize when we reach it, only 10km to go", as if it's some kind of precision centre-of-the-vortex thing...

The Centaur ship has to have extra-dimensional sensors for normal space reentry; they would do the equivalent of a full-spread electromagnetic scan to detect solid objects that could interfere with reentry, exactly to prevent what is going to happen.
So the ship automatically reintegrates in the volume with the safest electromagnetic return (provided it's above the safety threshold too).
The Centaurs however never had space wars and never thought of disrupting such scans (e.g. to lure an enemy to its destruction), have never thought about what any particular shapes might do to their safety scanner's returns, and since they have their nifty ED gadget, they never put their minds to other kinds of space propulsion.
If asked that very specific question, some Centaur scientist might have mumbled at last, "So... 'fake' a safe-volume hyperradar return... why yes, you could do that, I suppose, but... you'd need, say, a very large... a huge parabolic mirror, made out of conductive, EM-reflective material, and then put your trap in the focus. It's doable, but who would? Also such a mirror wouldn't be stable, it would catch the solar light like a sort of giant sail and fly away! I'd say this scenario is impractical and unlikely in the extreme."
Enter the Starfish - requiring large amounts of starlight to rebuild their ecosystem after a long stasis in the interstellar dark. They deploy the sail to brake their ship, and place the ship in the solar sail's focus. The solar sail is made up of metallic, EM-reflective material, and seen from hyperspace, the sail's focus is a safe haven among the whorls of the pulsar's solar wind...

I love the irony of this, but why would the scan being reflected back fake a safe zone? Wouldn’t the opposite be true?

@tenmillioncrabs you're right; and that's where you need some fast literary hand-waving. Fortunately, the scan being hyperdimensional, it's tantamount to magic and can behave however you like; it only has to sound vaguely plausible.

Perhaps Starfish have normal-space propulsion system similar to orion drive which accidently worked as said mirror for Centaur sensors. Autopilot identifies signal from own ship and waves it off as "radar ghost", a reflection from ionized gas, which got a false location away from cloud of gas. Also quite possible that Starfish creates some glitch  which desn't normally exist and matches noise profile (very low probablity case, but if Starfish intentionally generate false noise, that's possible?) and neural network of Centaur's autopilot discarded data as result of "noisy" sensor.

@tenmillioncrabs: if you need handwaivium to justify this, a safe bet is to say that the scan's signals destructively interfere when focused to a single point, yielding a "very safe " space there

Alien A and Alien B can't see each other while B is using it's fancy dimensional drive.  That's really all the reason you need.  In the real world, "I didn't see it" is the most common reason for running into things.  Heck, it's probably happened to me four times already today alone.  Alien B is bumbling about blindly.  The longer they do that, the more likely it is that they'll eventually run into something.  Murphy's Law all but guarantees it.  Alien A merely has the unfortunate honor of being that something.
But space is big, why do their paths even intersect...
Okay, fine.  Alien A's ship is propelled by solar sails, which means it's not very fast.  They'll take advantage of any speed boost they can get.  This particular region of space has a brief alignment between the central pulsar and the outer planets that will let Alien A's ship execute a multi-step gravity assist maneuver to pick up some speed and change direction.
Meanwhile, Alien B notices this alignment as well.  Making large/sharp turns is extremely hard while you're in extra-dimensional space because the extra dimensions cause the math to approach three-body problem levels of difficulty.  It's far easier to zero out, adjust your course, then re-engage the dimensional drive.  Alien B plans to do this while using the same gravity assist to make a fuel-efficient turn.
Both craft are trying to pass through the same rather narrow window at the same time.  Alien B's ship approaches Alien A's ship from a direction they didn't know existed.  When Alien B's ship zeroes out, it's like a big rig running at highway speeds turning a blind corner and rear-ending a slow-moving farm vehicle.
But Alien B's ship would have sensors to detect extra-dimensional collisions...
My neighbor's car has three different mirrors, a back-up camera, and 360-degree proximity sensors with alarms that make noise and vibrate the seat.  He still backs into my trash can regularly.  What's your point?

Pulsar planet
Both species are interested in this particular pulsar because it is particular: there is a pulsar planet orbiting it, and it's orbit is inside the very line-of-sight of pulsar's beam of emission!
How to ignore this unique opportunity to study ultra-high-energy cosmic rays source, so close to its emitter? What industrial, technological and strategic possibilites this configuration can provide?
So one species calculates where is best to approach the pulsar. The other species arrives at the same mathematical conclusion.

I thought the reason pulsars pulse is because their beam precesses. Is there even an orbit that would keep a plant inside the line-of-sight?

With beam precession, this scenario is even better, because is now a time frame, beyond a space locus, to the planet shield being attractive.

@ André L F S Bacci Huh?

I like the L2 point idea for why they happen to be on the same spot.
As for why they want to get close to the pulsar:
I am no expert but neutron matter could be a useful and rare resource for some technologies. It may be easy to extract it in tiny portions from other materials, but a pulsar (which is a neutron star) is like a huge treasure chest of this rare material.
I guess the radiation from a pulsar can be pretty destructive, especially from a close distance.
A thick ship armor (as of the Centaurs ship) or a water filled interior (as of the Starfish ship) can easily withstand the radiation, but a direct hit to an exposed sensor array can be deadly for the sensors.
Centaurs:
"Sir, our sensor array got destroyed by a massive radiation beam from the pulsar. We are no longer able to detect anything from the outside."
"What? Didn't we setup an extra front armor and a safe flight path to prevent this from happening?"
"Yes, but the radiation got reflected by a near object and hit the sensor from an unprotected angle."
"What caused this reflection?" (The Starfish's reflective solar sail)
"We don't know, the front armor prevented us to see small objects from the front direction - well anything smaller than a planet or moon."
"Prepare to return to normal space to replace the sensors before we crash into the planet or get too close to the star. It can't get much worse than navigating blind near a pulsar." (It can)
Starfish:
"We detected an object near our planned parking position, it seems to be a probe from an unknown species."
"Does that mean we have to search for a different parking position?"
"No, the probe is tiny and there is plenty of space."
"Good, get ready to park near the probe. We can analyze the probe and maybe we can get in contact with the ones who sent it." (They will)

Because the vile and duplicitous Alien C, who was in contact with both, tricked them into doing it by convincing them to be at just that spot at just that time. Despicable!

I’d rather not make anything that explicitly villainizes a group in this incident, nor do I have plans to introduce any other species who also happen to be in orbit of this star. Interesting idea though!

@tenmillioncrabs What would help in future is if you were to include such details (and all the other details you've posted in comments) in the body of the question right from the start.

@Escapeddentalpatient. Such a specific situation had not crossed my mind when I was writing the question.

It's worth doing so as it'll likely give you more on-point answers (and not disappoint answerers who can't read your mind) :) @tenmillioncrabs

Safest lading spot
The Starfish use an algorithm that calculates the safest spot near the pulsar to park. The Centaurs decide to find a safe spot to zero on the Extra Direction, convergence resulting in the same "safe" location.
Now, transponder beacons exist to warn away other ships from arriving at the same spot. Too bad these races haven't exchanged transponder signals yet/are incompatible. Their auto-pilot doesn't recognize signal from the other ship as a valid warning signal, and thus doesn't know to evade that spot.
